# Unable to connect to Oracle 11g database using JDBC on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, ojdbc

I'm trying to connect my Android app to Oracle Database Express Edition 11g hosted on my laptop. I'm testing the app on my phone with its hotspot ON to which the laptop is connected via WiFi.

I've added ojdbc14.jar to `app/libs` directory and selected `Add as Library` option on it through Android Studio.

I'm getting the following errors:

`Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.naming.Referenceable" on path: DexPathList`

`W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`

P.s. I know using a server is a better approach. Doing this for a client who wants to use it in a secure private network and they don't want to host a separate server for the database connection.

I read elsewhere that I need to use Async task for connecting JDBC but I'm not sure how; consider me a beginner. All other answers I found related to this keep going off topic. I just want to know how to make JDBC work on Android, considering the risks.

Here's my `MainActivity.java`:

```java
package com.absingh.apptest;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.42.49:1521:XE";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "myusername";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "mypassword";

    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        try {
            this.connection = createConnection();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from testtable");
            while(rs.next()) {
                stringBuffer.append( rs.getString(1)+"\n");
            }
            tv.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName(driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public static Connection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        return createConnection(DEFAULT_DRIVER, DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Comment: The package `javax.naming` is not available on Android. Looks like you are using a Oracle Java driver for J2SE, but you need one for Android.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured it out :) It needed the "uses Internet" permission to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.
The code in the question works fine if you add this above the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I'll leave the question be, in case someone else gets the same problem.